# How to make the parent element fit its floated children as long as they aren't wider than the window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to center a list of floating elements, but since it's a masonry I can't make them `inline`. A container would be needed, that much is obvious, but I couldn't find anywhere how do make it do this:

[image]

Ignore the margins here, they don't matter, it's just so each separate child element can be seen. And yes, the parent isn't centered, but it could be. The important part is that it dynamically fits the child elements and its width isn't 100% all the time.

Already tried floating the parent, in that case the child elements only make a single column.

Comment: The question is slightly not clear, but interesting. Did you try using flexbox?

Comment: Could you please post any code or your ideas by using JS fiddle? So that we will more understanding on the issue.

Comment: Not sure I understand correctly what you mean. SO you have a container that uses masonry to display your children. And the issue you face is that :1 - have to have a fix width of the parent to get it working? or 2- 100% width of the parent doesn't make the trick or 3 - ?
May be try to provide an image with your layout issue.

Comment: @DianaR Your solution 1 will be better in this case.

Comment: @SandeepKushwah than we need the css and the exact jqeury code used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just set the parent's width the product of that of the maximum numbers of children with each child's width (if the child's width is constant)?

```
 var x = $(child).outerWidth();
 $(window).resize(function() {
      $(parent).width(Math.floor($(window).width() / x)*x);
 });
```

Comment: I presume because the children are added on the fly after the container is already configured and created.

Comment: @DianaR that shouldn't matter as long as the child's width is constant (as shown in the gif).

Comment: than what you suggest has to be executed each time a new child is added, is that what you mean?

Comment: @DianaR the animation was to show what the parent would look like with a different amount of children. This was exactly what I needed, thanks.